# Using a for loop to check order of numbers, decreasing and increasing order

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

User will input five values (range 2-9), into an array. Code is then supposed to check whether or not the five values entered are either in decreasing or increasing order.

Example:

2, 3, 4, 5, 6 - would result in a bool value set to 'true'

6, 5, 4, 3, 2 - would have the same result as above

If however there are two of the same numbers or the sequence is not in order, either increasing or decreasing then the bool value is 'false'

Example:

2, 3, 2, 5, 6 - false

2, 3, 5, 4, 6 - false

7, 8, 6, 5, 4 - false

I have completed two cases individually, when there is a pair and when checking for increasing order.

For loop I have set up to check increasing order/pair

```
for(int count = 0; count < 5; count++){
    if((cards[count] > cards[count + 1]) || (cards[count] == cards[count + 1]))
        result = false;
    else
        continue;
}
```

For loop I made to check decreasing order

```
for(int count = 0; count < 5; count++){
    if((cards[count] < cards[count+ 1]) || (cards[count] == cards[count + 1]))
        result = false;
    else
        continue;
}
```

The for loop that is meant to check increasing order does not work, and lastly putting it all together. I tried breaking it down into individuals parts in order to make it easier.

Edit:

per assignment guidelines, I am unable to sort the array or anything that modifies it. creating a copy and working with that is also not allowed.

Comment: The condition can be condensed to `if(cards[count] >= cards[count+1])` and similarly for the other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need the `else continue;` – that will happen automatically.

Second, you're on the right track, but you have an error in your array accesses. Your loop goes from 0 to 4 (when it reaches 5 it will end the loop). When you're looking at item 4 (the 5th item in the array) of the array and compare it to item 5 (the sixth item in the array), you're comparing against a value that isn't there. This can cause undefined behavior.

The solution is to set the condition on your loop to `< 4` so that on the last loop you compare the second-to-last item with the last item.

Answer (score 0):

You can check monotonicity in one loop.

```
bool isArrayMonotonic(std::vector<int>& arr) {
    if (arr.empty()) {
        return true;
    }
    bool isAscending = true, isDescending = true;
    int pre = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
        isAscending = isAscending && arr[i] > pre;
        isDescending = isDescending && arr[i] < pre;
        pre = arr[i];
    }
    return isAscending || isDescending;
}
```